# Network between 2 docker-composes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to create a communication channel between 2 completely different docker-composes? I know I can just open the ports to the OS and connect through them but I want a more restricted access, something like a LAN over 2 different groups of containers.

Also I am holding back using Swarm and other managers like it for now.

Something like a link: instruction but over composes?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Shit, I overlooked the documentation part that was addressing it...

[Here it is](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#/using-a-pre-existing-network) in case someone needs it.

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```